# Unable to get props.children while using Provider in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am a newbie to React. I am partially following this tutorial [full-stack-redux-tutorial](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html) for creating my web application. I am using  from 'react-redux' to pass the data that I receive from the server to one of my components. My index.jsx file looks like the following

```
     import routes from './routes.jsx';

         const socket = io(`${location.protocol}//${location.hostname}:8090`);

    socket.on('curr_all_news', curr_all_news =>
      store.dispatch(setCurrentAllNews(curr_all_news))
    );

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  remoteActionMiddleware(socket)
)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

            ReactDOM.render((
              <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                  <Router>{routes}</Router>
                </Provider>
              </MuiThemeProvider>), 
                    document.getElementById('root')
            );
```

The routes.jsx file looks like the following

```
import MainNav from './components/navbar.jsx';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import {HomePageContainer} from './components/SportsHome.jsx';

    const routes =<MainNav component = {App}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
            <Route path ="/login" component = {LoginPage}/>
            <Route path ="/signup" component = {SignUpPage}/>
        </Switch> 
    </MainNav>;
```

My App.jsx has the following code

```
import { Component } from 'react';

    export default class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return this.props.children;
        }
    };
```

Finally, my homepage has the following code

```
export class HomePage extends PureComponent{
  render() {
          return <div className="news-holder">
            <div className="containerWrapper">
              <div className="s-row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                  Checking the workng of custom written div
                    <NewsPanel {...this.props} />
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>;
  }
};

function mapNewsToProps(curr_all_news){
  console.log("curr_all_news here:",curr_all_news);
  return {
    news:curr_all_news
  }
}
export const HomePageContainer = connect(mapNewsToProps,actionCreators)(HomePage);
```

My question is I am unable to get the value of curr_all_news on my home page.i.e I am only getting an empty list `(List {size: 0, _origin: 0, _capacity: 0, _level: 5, _root: undefined…})`as the value of curr_all_news in the mapNewsToProp function instead of what is supposed to be a list of objects. I am able to fetch the value from the server and bring it to the client via socket but then in the App.jsx which is the component given to the MainNav the render function never gets called.I am unable to figure out what I am missing.Thanks for the help in advance

My navbar.jsx looks like below

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

class MainNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         loggedIn: 1,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="/">SportsSpot</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nfl">
                               <NavItem>NFL</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/mlb">
                               <NavItem>MLB</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nba">
                               <NavItem>NBA</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nhl">
                               <NavItem>NHL</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>   
                        </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <LinkContainer to="/login">
                                <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                            <NavItem>Sign Up</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <div className="content">
                        {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

MainNav.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

export default MainNav;
```

Comment: The problem is that App component doesn't specify children in routes. To be sure I would like to see the code for navbar.jsx

Comment: I have included my navbar.jsx code as well.

Comment: This  looks wrong to me `render() { return this.props.children; }` :(

Comment: @btzr, that is wrong, but the OP is not using the App component anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct a few things in your code.

1. You App component returns `this.props.children`. However you can only return a single element from a component. So you should wrap it within a div

   ```
   export default class App extends Component {
       render() {
          return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
       }
   };
   ```
2. MainNav takes a component as a prop but you are never really using it. Change the structure to the following

   ```
       const routes =<MainNav>
             <App>
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
                 <Route path ="/login" component = {LoginPage}/>
                 <Route path ="/signup" component = {SignUpPage}/>
             </Switch> 
             </App>
         </MainNav>;
   ```
3. You need not export the HomePage class if you are connecting it with Redux store.

   ```
    class HomePage extends PureComponent{
   ```

and then use it like

```
    export default connect(mapNewsToProps,actionCreators)(HomePage);
```

and import it as

```
   import HomePageContainer from './components/SportsHome.jsx';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It worked.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your structuring is a bit wonky, take a look at this snippet from a similar project I have that may provide some better understanding.

You App component definitely looks wrong.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        {routes}
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/path0" component={Container0} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/path1" component={Container1} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/path2" component={Container2} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/path3" component={Container3} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/path4" component={Container4} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/path5" component={Container5} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```